# определение максимального возможного размера строки в стеке

Tags: c++, строки, память, stl

```
#include <iostream>

// заголовок
const std::ostream& os = std::cout << "\t\t\tR\tA\tM\n" << std::endl;

int main()
{    
    std::string s;
    try {
        s.resize(s.max_size());
        std::cout << s.max_size();
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc)
    {
        std::cout << "Generated an exception std::bad_alloc\n"
                  <<"RAM_size ==  s.max_size()?..";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Не очень то ясно, почему все таки генерируется исключение, если размер строки устанавливаю на максимально возможный?..  И как определить  размер строки, не генерирующий исключение?  Просветите пожалуйста

Comment: Это максимально возможный размер, определяемый реализацией. Никак не связан с физически достпуным объемом памяти.

Comment: Во-первых, содержимое `std::string` не хранится "в стеке". Во-вторых, сначала надо было бы распечатать значение `s.max_size()`. Без этого ничего осмысленного сказать нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала вам надо было бы распечатать значение `max_size()` - тогда стало бы понятно, почему не удается выполнить выделение памяти.

Например, в GCC `max_size()` возвращает `0x7fffffffffffffff`, то есть половину диапазона 64-битного целого типа, половину диапазона `std::size_t`. А это, как известно, максимальный размер объекта/максимальный размер массива/максимальный размер динамически выделяемого блока памяти в GCC (и во многих других реализациях).

Так как блок памяти, который `std::string` будет пытаться выделять для хранения строки такой длины будет включать дополнительную информацию, неудивительно, что выделение памяти заканчивается безуспешно. Почему авторы станадартной библиотеки GCC не "урезали" величину `max_size()` соответствующим образом - вопрос к ним. Но формальной ошибки в этом нет, ибо практической возможности создания строки такого размера вам никто не гарантировал.

Comment: Я ошибочно подумал, что может быть  для каждого обьекта std::allocator  определяет величину  max_size(). Вы правы, я не  проверяя задал вопрос, надеясь  получать ответы, похожие на ваш: содержащихся полезных информаций.   В итоге  неясно только одно: зачем ограничивать количество символов таким большим числом, если практически обычно столько не помещается  в памяти? Но как вы говорите, это вопрос к разработчикам...

Answer (score 2):

Как указано, например, тут [тыц](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/max_size/). *max_size* - это **потенциально** возможный максимальный размер строки, определяемый либо параметрами системы, либо ограничениями, заданными в реализации. И опять же, как сказано в описании по ссылке, не дается **никаких** гарантий, что данный размер может быть достигнут.

Answer (score 2):

Максимально возможный - это сколько в переменную размера влезет, а не сколько можно реально получить. На 32-разрядном получите, например, 2147483647 - но столько памяти не выделяемо в принципе (в 64-разрядной все еще хуже).

Как узнать? Да вряд ли есть разумный способ... типа методом типа бинарного поиска смотреть, когда памяти не хватает :) Но вопрос - зачем вам это знать заранее?

Comment: Я вопрос задал больше для второй части вашего ответа.  Почему хочу знать?..  Просто хотел знать все то, что вы мне рассказали

Comment: Оно еще даже в рамках одной программы может кардинально меняться - фрагментация памяти, например, или еще что...

Comment: Ну, при желании узнать можно. Посмотреть максимальный размер стека, посмотреть в /proc/self/maps в каких он адресах, взять какой-нибудь адрес в текущем фрейме и вычислить